# A jQuery function that affect any object

Tags: jquery, html

Create a jQuery function which fades out any object that is clicked on.

This is an assignment question. I have a problem on creating a single function that will fade any object/element.

I have created four paragraphs and four buttons in which I have created four jQuery functions; whenever I click a button it fade out a paragraph.

Now the question need one jquery function which will do the task specified.
Please assist me with some hints on how to.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <title>JQuery in Action</title>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#test1").click(function(){
            $("#heading1").fadeOut();
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#test2").click(function(){
            $("#paragraph1").fadeOut();
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#test3").click(function(){
            $("#heading2").fadeOut();
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#test4").click(function(){
            $("#paragraph2").fadeOut();
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="test1">For Heading 1</button>
    <button id="test2">For Paragraph 1</button>
    <button id="test3">For Heading 2</button>
    <button id="test4">For Paragraph 2</button>

    <h1 id="heading1">Learning the basics of JQuery - JQuery in Action</h1>
    <p id="paragraph1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel aeterno propriae id, dolore pertinacia eu vix. 
    </p>

    <h1 id="heading2">Testing continue - JQuery in Action</h1>
    <p id="paragraph2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel aeterno propriae id, dolore pertinacia eu vix. 
    </p>

</body>
```

Comment: can you explain your code please?

Comment: @JayantaBiswas if you have some suggestion of how can I get one jquery function, it should be dynamic, whether elements are 10 or any it should still works

Comment: wait for few mins sir

Comment: @JayantaBiswas - thanks that works fine. Can you recommend any tutorial with these kind of functions, like the one you wrote.

Comment: sorry sir. But i think jQuery.net is best and some video tutorials in youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sir it may help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <title>JQuery in Action</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button data-target="heading1">For Heading 1</button>
    <button data-target="paragraph1">For Paragraph 1</button>
    <button data-target="heading2">For Heading 2</button>
    <button data-target="paragraph2">For Paragraph 2</button>

    <h1 id="heading1">Learning the basics of JQuery - JQuery in Action</h1>
    <p id="paragraph1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel aeterno propriae id, dolore pertinacia eu vix. 
    </p>

    <h1 id="heading2">Testing continue - JQuery in Action</h1>
    <p id="paragraph2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel aeterno propriae id, dolore pertinacia eu vix. 
    </p>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").on('click', function(event) {
                var target = $(this).data('target');
                $("#" + target).fadeOut();

                event.preventDefault();
            });

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do some research here and read up on fadein(). 
They give some great examples to help you along! 
--> http://api.jquery.com/fadein/